# How to reference a boxed theorem?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, tcolorbox

I was trying to reference the theorem number

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,breakable,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black
  }
}{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{Theorem}{First}{}\label{first}
test
\end{Theorem}

Here we refer Theorem \ref{first}
\begin{Theorem}{Second}{}\label{second}
test
\end{Theorem}
Here we refer Theorem \ref{second}
\end{document}
```

But it is like I'm referencing the subsection number rather than the theorem number. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for definition is

`\newtcbtheorem[init options]{Theorem box name}{Theorem title}{options}{prefix for label}`

and the correct usage is

`\begin{foo}{title}{labelname}`

when the theorem has the box name foo. Later on, use `\ref{thm:labelname}`, assuming the prefix is `thm`. The `:` is added automatically, but can changed with the option `label separator`.

This said, the label is added by `tcbtheorem` from the 2nd argument of the theorem. `\label{foo}` outside would use the old `\@currentlabel` reference which points to the first subsection in the OP.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,breakable,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black
  }
}{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{Theorem}{First}{first}
test
\end{Theorem}

Here we refer Theorem \ref{thm:first}
\begin{Theorem}{Second}{second}
test
\end{Theorem}
Here we refer Theorem \ref{thm:second}
\end{document}
```

[image]